# Sorting a stack in ascending order? (using only 3 stacks)

Tags: c++, sorting, stack

So I'm doing some homework for CompSci 2 and the assignment requires us to sort a single stack (of five numbers) in ascending order using **only** 3 stacks - much like a Tower of Hanoi problem - but there are no rules on whether a larger can be placed on a smaller number, etc.

I'm essentially trying to figure out a process on how to sort any number against another in the stack, but I'm at a bit of a loss - in trying to formulate an idea I came up with this: I could pop the top number off the stack, place it in another stack (say, stack 3), compare it to the next number in the original stack, and if it's less than it, I would put the number in stack 3 into stack 2.  But then I ran into the problem of order - if the number is less than the one after it, but *isn't* less than another number in the stack, my final result would be out of order.

Could someone help me out here in figuring out method would work best?

Comment: The tower of hanoi is somewhat a subset of this problem. Relax the requirement for placing discs to Disc1 <= Disc2 and see what algorithm jumps out at you.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: The solution to Towers of Hanoi is well-documented; does that one not work for you?

Comment: @JasonBaker The issue with Tower of Hanoi was that you're not allowed to place a larger number on top of a smaller number - however this problem doesn't have that constraint, I figured that would pose a numerical problem - at least it stumped me when I was drawing out the problem, but I'll try it and see what happens anyway.

Comment: Okay, missed that restriction. The Towers of Hanoi algorithm would still be *correct*, obviously, but you could likely improve on the runtime with small modifications. Not sure if runtime is a concern for you or not

Comment: Any other restrictions? Are other variables permitted?

Comment: @Beta I don't know whether she would allow other variables but the first line literally says "Create a program, named stacks, that does the following (sorting numbers in ascending order) using ONLY three separate linked-based stacks, named stack1, stack2, and stack3" so I suppose when you input a number into a stack you could use a variable, but I'm not sure outside of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm for an insertion sort based one too, but I find @Beta's answer a bit confusing, so I worked on my own, written as Pseudocode.

We'll name the three stacks `source`, `temp` and `result`. And their top items as`*source`, `*temp` and `*result` respectively.

We'll try to keep the `result` stack always sorted with the biggest items at the bottom and smallest at the top.

```
While `source` isn't empty we:
    While `*source` is bigger than `*result`
        put `*result` onto `temp`.
    put `*source` onto `result`.
    Put all the items from `temp` back onto `result`.
```

Comment: So at the first pass, *source will always go to result since the stack is empty in the beginning, correct?

Comment: Yes. Actually the rule should probably be "While result isn't empty and `*source` is bigger than `*result`." I'm currently implementing it myself to verify it.

Comment: @Raphel M. I'm using the numbers in a previous comment (7,1,9,6,4) to check it as well (7 being at the top), and I ended up with the result 1,4,6,9,7, so I think on the first pass, you may want to put *source in temp, then continue as you wrote.

**ETA:** turns out that didn't work either, so disregard that suggestion

Comment: @TaiM. hmm, my implementation seems to work with random numbers: http://ideone.com/5qcSNL gonna try with your numbers in a second. **Edit:** works for me: http://ideone.com/Rzijct

Comment: @RapahelM. Ah, I wrote  a step wrong, it actually does work, hah.

Comment: @TaiM. hmm, putting only one item from `temp` back to `result` instead of all? =P

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using stack 1 and 2 together as a traversable list, then apply a bubble sort using stack 3 as temporary holding.

Comment: +1 This has the advantage that it requires no other state information-- you can determine the next move just by peeking at the three stacks.

Comment: If we can have state information, why not move all the data into "state information" and perform a quicksort?

Answer (score 1):

I would do an insertion sort. Stack 1 is the original, unsorted numbers, stack 2 is in ascending order (the last-inserted element is the largest), stack 3 is in descending order, and the smallest element in stack 3 (which is on top) is larger than the largest element in stack 2 (which is also on top).

This method, like @AMADANONinc.'s, requires no memory of state or other variables, and I think it's faster.

Call the top elements of 1, 2 and 3 "A", "B" and "C", respectively.

**EDIT:** I've rewritten the algorithm, and I think it's now rigorous. Try these rules in order, and when you move an element, go back to the beginning.

1. If stack 1 and stack 3 are both empty, then we're done.

   If stack 1 is empty (but 3 is not) then move C to stack 2.

   If B is larger than A, move B to stack 3.

   If C is smaller than A, move C to stack 2.

   (Since none of the previous rules applies) move A to stack 2 or stack 3.

For instance, suppose stack 1 starts out as {22,44,11,55,33} (33 is on top). By rule 5, move 33 to 2. By rule 5, move 55 to 2. By rule 3, move 55 to 3. By rule 3, move 33 to 3. By rule 5, move 11 to 2. By rule 4, move 33 to 2. By rule 5, move 44 to 3. By rule 3, move 33 to 3. By rule 5, move 22 to 2. By rule 2, move 33, 44 and 55 to 2. By rule 1, halt.

Comment: In your first statement, I'm essentially moving the top item to stack 2 or 3, then the next item after that into the other non-empty stack, correct? I'm trying to simulate this on a board to make sure I understand properly.

Comment: @TaiM.: Move the first item to stack 2 or 3; let's say 2. Then compare A and B; if B is larger then (according to the second rule), move it to stack 3, and if A is larger then move it to stack 3. I see that my first rule is incomplete-- let me see if I can correct it...

Comment: I found your explanation a bit confusing too and tried to write my own one in Pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest method for a 3 stack sort is a polyphase merge sort. With only 5 numbers and the fact that 5 is a polyphase friendly Fibonacci number helps. Assume the stacks are A, B, C, and that the 5 numbers are initially on A. For this example the numbers start off in reverse order. In the diagram below, the front (first element) of the stack is on the left. Vertical bars represent run boundaries. The comments refer to the next step to be performed. The comment merge means to merge 1 run from two stacks onto third stack.

```
A            B            C
|5|4|3|2|1|                             pop/push 2 from A to B        
|3|2|1|      |4|5|                      merge A + B to C ascending
|2|1|        |5|         |4 3|          merge A + B to C descending
|1|                      |2 5|4 3|      merge A + C to B ascending
             |5 2 1|     |4 3|          merge B + C to A descending
|1 2 3 4 5|                             done
```

Total number of moves (pop/push) = 14.

A generic polyphase merge sort for 3 stacks is somewhat complicated. First moving elements from A to B and C (C if number of elements is not a Fibonacci number), then determining if the first merge is ascending or descending (they alternate after that), and keeping track of run size changes. If anyone is interested, I can post example code.